# How to make directories for an specific user using C, CGI, HTML?

Tags: c, cgi, system-calls, mkdir, user-permissions

and i have a issue, im creating directories using C, CGI and HTML, i started with 2 source codes, one is this:

```
/*
 * newdir.c - Create a directory
 */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     printf("\n#Argumentos: %d\n", argc);
     if(mkdir(argv[1], 0777)) {
      perror("mkdir");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And i have this other one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Everything here is the same as sampleprogram.c except that 
// there are differences when we have to read in the string
int main(void)
{
  char *data;
  char* s = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%s%c%c\n",
     "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);

  int length = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
  int j =0;
  char c;
  c = getchar();
  data = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1) ); 
  while ( c != EOF && j < length ) {
    //read in one character
    data[j] = c;
    c = getchar();
    j++;

  }
  data[j] = '\0';

  printf("<TITLE>Make directorys</TITLE>");
  printf("<H3> Make new directory \n <br> %s ");


if(data == NULL) {
    printf("<P>Error! Error in passing data from form to script.");
    return 0;
  }

  char delimiters[] = "&";

  char* str = strtok( data, delimiters);

     sscanf(str, "s=%s", s);
     int i;
     for (i=0; i < strlen(s); i++ ) {
       if (s[i] == '+')
     s[i] = ' ';

     }
      str = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
     //s is the name collected from the text area in the html file
     if(mkdir(s, 0777)) {
      perror("mkdir");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  return 0;
}
```

so what I did was add the first code to the second other, the other code collects information from a text field of a html and this is processed by the CGI script.
It works perfect , but the directory is created for the user " daemon " and I can not add anything inside if I do not set the permissions to 777 again from console, why this happens ? something is wrong?
PD: if i run the first code from console works perfect, i'm the user :(

Comment: `malloc(100 * sizeof(char))` is very wrong. 1. `sizeof(char)` is going to be always one, it's specified by the c standard. 2. You don't need `malloc()` for a known fixed size. `str = strtok()` and the following `sscanf()` are a mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to C programming , these codes I got from another user on the web, this works well , does not give me any errors, the only thing that happens is the directory that was created is as user " daemon " , this should not happen if I'm giving 777 permissions

Comment: This code is really bad, it's leaking memory and it's very unsafe. Use PHP for that or any other scripting language, it doesn't have to be *c*, in fact it's the worse possible way to do it. It doesn't have anything to do with permissions. The file owner will be *daemon* regardless of the permissions.

Comment: Using `strlen()` in a `for` loop is really bad practice.

Comment: I haven't seen code so badly written.

Comment: Yeah, thank u for the tips, i need to do this in C, that is the rule for my project, i'll see how to fix these errors, then the user will always be " daemon " i don't knew that ty for ur answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no way to really solve this, because the user that executes the scripts/programs is the *`daemon`* user. It's the way you setup your web server, the web server itself is run by the *`daemon`* user, and that means that every script/program invoked by the web server will be run by the same user too.

Also, both [c](/questions/tagged/c) programs you posted are really poorly coded, and it doesn't seem like you need to write them in the [c](/questions/tagged/c) language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *content_length;
    char *data;
    char s[100];

    content_length = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    if (content_length != NULL)
    {
        int length;
        int j;
        char c;

        printf("Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\n");

        length = atoi(content_length);
        c = getchar();
        data = malloc(length + 1);
        if (data != NULL)
        {
            const char *delimiters;
            char *token;

            delimiters = "&";
            while ((c != EOF) && (j < length))
            {
                data[j] = c;
                c = getchar();
                j++;
            }
            data[j] = '\0';

            printf("<TITLE>Make directorys</TITLE>");
            printf("<H3> Make new directory \n <br> %s ");

            token = strtok(data, delimiters);
            if ((token != NULL) && (sscanf(str, "s=%99s", s)  == 1))
            {
                int i;

                for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
                {
                    if (s[i] == '+')
                        s[i] = ' ';
                }

                if (mkdir(s, 0777))
                {
                    perror("mkdir");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            free(data);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ty, then is not posible to make dirs for an specific user, running a script?

Comment: It would help if you give more information, what kind of web server you have? how is it configured? what user would you like to own the files? what operating system it is?

Comment: I'm using Linux mint, apache server, and i just configured the CGI execution files in httpd.conf, and i need create files and directories for the user logged  in my system, or any user (except "daemons" users of course)

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Web servers are not meant to do that.

Comment: It's my college project , we need make these calls to the system using C , and we not have much knowledge in C programming, because our main programming language is python then we suggested make the user interface using HTML and CGI

Comment: Yes but why do you want to create a directory to be accessed by the user through the webserver. That's wrong. You only need the *daemon* user to access it, and send it's content back to the client. And if you need to create a new directory for each user it's still the *daemon* user who will have the responsibility of doing it.

Comment: That is the question that I have , then this is not possible , the user will always be " daemon " This information is important to say that we had this problem by creating directories, because we can't use the system() function too, anyway thanks for your answer it will help me a lot to defend my project

Comment: You should say that it doesn't make sense anyway because the user is not supposed to access the server through the web server program, in this case *apache*.